# How to atomically create a file in a non-existing folder?

Tags: c#, file, directory, atomic

Given a path to a file, I would like to create this file, and the string of directories leading to it if they don't exist ; but I don't want any other instance of my program to be able to see the base directory existing without the file in it.

Basically, I want to atomically create the required directories and the file at once. From what I understood, it must be done in 2 steps (create directory, create file), so I was thinking about using a lock file, but the same problem applies : where do I create the lock file ? I don't know how many levels of folders need to be created, and at some point down the path, I might loose writing rights, so there is no "safe place" for a lock file.

Then I thought about using a lock directory instead of a lock file, but I couldn't find any "test and set" method to create directories (`Directory.CreateDirectory(path)` doesn't tell you if it did something).

So what's the right way to do it ?

Comment: It depends what else is going to be trying to make the folder+file.  Is it your app?  Use a system-wide Mutex / other IPC.  You could look at NTFS API, it is transactional, although you likely need to P/Invoke for it

Comment: What's wrong with using a temp file? Random file name. Low chance any other app would know about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create the directory and file under a temporary name and atomically rename the directory to the final name.

Or use transactional NTFS (much harder).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Mutex class which allows you to sync interprocess.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex.aspx

In pseudocode for all processes

```
grab the mutex
try
 check or create directory and file
finally
release the mutex
```

This works for local program instances running on the same pc. Not specified, but for program instances across a network that use the same database you could implement mutex-like functionality in the database.

Comment: hmm, except if several machines can access the directory on a share... but I didn't specify that in my question.